# For Finetuning Llama 2, what form of data is required?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, finetuning, chatbot, llm

I am working on a customer service chatbot project. I have files of different product's manuals on which i need to train the LLM which is Llama 2. As these are manuals so they not in Q/A form. In this case, can i finetune it on these same manuals or do i require info in specific format for finetuning.